# Create a span size between span3 and span2 in bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 rows with growing columns... az picture below. how can I create third row with bootstrap? ( I use bootstrap 2.3.2 and jquery.min-v1.8.2)
[image]

Comment: they are bootstrap classes... I didn't write them!

Comment: I know that, but you can use client developer tools (Chrome Developer Tools, Firebug or F12 tools) to see what those CSS classes are doing and try to determine what custom CSS class you can make to create the `span2.5` style you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create our own 30-column based bootstrap layout and use classes "span10" to have span with width equal to "span3" and so on.
To do this calculate column width for 30-column layout and specify it on page: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html#variables